# Google Map not working in android device/phone

Tags: android, google-maps

i have one query .

While i'm running my application in Emulator that time Map is working fine.

but when i run application into android device at that time it is not showing map.

can anybody suggest me is there is any problem in map Android map key or is there is any settings or permission need to do..

Thanks

Comment: Do you have proper internet connectivity on your device ?

Comment: Are you running the app on your device with the same certificate? when you said is not showing map, you mean that you see a grey background or the app crashes?

Comment: yes i have proper internet connectivity.. it showing proper overlay.. but there is problem in loading Map

Comment: @SeRPRo : it is showing grey background in android mobile.

Comment: i m getting this error while creating MD5

Comment: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_14\bin>keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keys
tore "c:\db.keystore"
Enter keystore password:
keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Alias <androiddebugkey> does not exist

Answer (score 2):

Is your map key correct?

You have to generate the android map key with the keystore you are using to upload the apk to the market or to test in different phones.

Here you have all the information you need:

http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html

Hope this helps...